# How to search for compound words, and get the word parts returned

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, database-agnostic, string-searching

I need to be able to search for **compound words** like "*menneskerettighedsforkæmperens*" (the human rights activist's) and find the words "*menneske*" (human), "*rettighed*" (right) and "*forkæmper*" (activist).

I have all the words (and hundreds of thousands of other words) listed in MySQL, all in separate rows with additional information about each word (like hyphenation, which is what I need the DB to return), but I need to search a lot of words at the same time, which can be painfully slow.

I'm currently using a MySQL database, but willing to switch it out for something better suiting my needs, maybe some kind of NoSQL or elasticsearch. But I haven't been able to find any examples of how to accomplish what I'm looking for in any other type of databases. So if anyone can help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would look for a library that specializes in splitting compound words.  Search Java, PHP, Perl, etc.  SQL is not likely to be involved.

If you must use a database, then consider this for a piece of the algorithm:

```
SELECT word FROM words
    WHERE word < 'menneskerettighedsforkæmperens'
    ORDER BY word DESC
    LIMIT 5;
```

That is likely to return a few compound words that begin with 'menneske' and perhaps 'menneske', itself.

In MySQL, that query will be quite fast (assuming an index on `word`).  You would need some code in addition to a few SQL calls.